# AdventureWorks2012 mdf error message when downloading file

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I am trying to download AdventureWorks2012.mdf. The link I am using is (https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases). I then select the first option "adventure-works-2012-dw-data-file.mdf".

The link seems to download, but then when I go to open it I get an error:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel

I have a macbook air and I have installed Microsoft by way of a virtual machine. Given all of this information, how am I supposed to resolve this issue so I can get the file to download? I already have SQL Server 2012 installed on my Microsoft.

Comment: You need to open SQL Server Management Studio and "attach" the mdf file.  You can't just double-click on it to open,.

Comment: As Paul suggested - that link also has instructions for attaching. And pay attention to the file you selected. Did you really want the data warehouse version and not the OLTP version? Typically one does not start learning sql server using the DW version.